# How can I redirect from a Permalink to a new permalink?

Tags: wordpress, symfony, redirect, web, deployment

To add more detail, my current situation is that we are moving from Symfony2 to Wordpress (resources choice). Usually the redirect would require a relative link as source and a permalink as destination.

Let's call the domain http://example.com

Users with old links such as http://example.com/article/[id] need to be redirected to the new urls which is something like http://example.com/title

We have around 200 links that require redirecting and as you can see the new urls don't allow much for automating the process. My issue is if we set the .htaccess under the old installation and change the domain for it to example2.com, none of the users will ever stumble on it to be redirected.

Which leads me to ask if its possible to have a permalink on both ends of the redirect. I am open to any other suggestions to how to tackle the issue, except the old and new url formatting can't be changed in the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most efficient way of doing it but, I get a list of all the links I need to redirect and a list of the new urls they are directing to and do a 301 redirect in the htaccess. This will change all indexes on google so they will show up without any issues.

```
Redirect 301 /article/1 /title
```